# Problem adding xbox 360 as windows 7 media center extender over wireless

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, windows-media-center, xbox360

Trying to add XBOX 360 as Windows Media Center Extender on Windows 7 Pro machine. I have completely disabled Windows firewall and wireless security, with no luck.

To troubleshoot, I have:

- Disabled Windows Firewall completely
- Disabled Wireless Authentication & Encryption
- Same problem on multiple computers
- Verified that I have no problems over a wired connection.

Here are some other factors:

- Router/Access Point is Linksys Wireless-N Broadband Router WRT160N
- Using latest version of AVG Free on computers. Have tried disabling resident shield.

Here is the error I am getting on my pc:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved problem. I needed to go here and allow my xbox:

[image]

Then needed to check types of media that I wanted to share:
[image]

Comment: Please mark this as your accepted answer, so other users will know that this has been answered and accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my research and experience the "Configuration Error" problem occurs for a variety of reasons. Here are some of the common ones.

1. Corrupt Media Center Certificate.
2. Corrupt Default User Profile.

I solved the problem in my case by re-establishing the permissions for the Default user profile in c:\users\Default so that the administrative group had full permissions.